# HTML Mixed Encodings?

Tags: java, html, parsing, encoding, web-crawler

First I would like to say thank you for the help in advance.

I am currently writing a web crawler that parses HTML content, strips HTML tags, and then spell checks the text which is retrieved from the parsing.

Stripping HTML tags and spell checking has not caused any problems, using JSoup and Google Spell Check API.

I am able to pull down content from a URL and passing this information into a byte[] and then ultimately a String so that it can be stripped and spell checked.  I am running into a problem with character encoding.

For example when parsing http://www.testwareinc.com/...

**Original Text:** We’ve expanded our Mobile Web and Mobile App testing services.

... the page is using ISO-8859-1 according to meta tag...

**ISO-8859-1 Parse:** Weve expanded our Mobile Web and Mobile App testing services.

... then trying using UTF-8...

**UTF-8 Parse:** We�ve expanded our Mobile Web and Mobile App testing services.

***Question***
Is it possible that HTML of a webpage can include a mix of encodings?  And how can that be detected?

Comment: dealing with text sucks. Good luck!

Comment: From a very quick glance (just in the browser, not in a hex editor), the character looks like a valid ISO-8559-1 character. Why are you thinking there are two encodings at play here? Is it not possible that your parser somehow simply swallows the character?

Comment: Thanks cdeszaq I have been working on this crawler for about 6 months and parsing is the only part that has caused me problems at every turn but I kinda knew it would since "in-the-wild" HTML can be quite different from site to site.

Comment: I am thinking CP1252 and ISO-8859-1 are playing games with eachother.  I used juniversalchardet as explained below and it notified me that the content on the page is not in fact ISO-8859-1.  At least I can find out what I should use to be able to get the most data possible if I loose a bit oh well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the apostrophe is coded as a 0x92 byte, which according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is an unassigned/private code point.

From there on, it looks like the browser falls back by assuming it's a non-encoded 1-byte Unicode code point : [+0092](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0092/index.htm) (*Private Use Two*) which appears to be represented as an apostrophe. No wait, if it's one byte, it's more probably [cp1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252): Browsers must have a fallback strategy according to the advertised CP, such as ISO-8859-1 -> CP1252.

So no mix of encoding here but as others said a broken document. But with a fallback heuristic that will sometimes help, sometimes not.

If you're curious enough, you may want to dive into FF or Chrome's source code to see exactly what they do in such a case.

Comment: You are correct when running juniversalchardet I see the page is actually CP1252 and not ISO-8859-1 as set in meta tags.  When decoding the InputStream with CP1252 as the Charset the apostrophe appears correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Having more than 1 encoding in a document isn't a mixed document, it is a broken document.

Unfortunately there are a lot of web pages that use an encoding that doesn't match the document definition, or contains some data that is valid in the given encoding and some content that is invalid.

There is no good way to handle this.  It is possible to try and guess the encoding of a document, but it is difficult and not 100% reliable.  In cases like yours, the simplest solution is just to ignore parts of the document that can't be decoded.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately, this is what I was afraid of.  It looks like I will be able to detect with some accuracy the encoding using juniversalchardet.  But I am sure even this will cause issues.  For example using juniversalchardet had found that the HTML is using cp1252 and not ISO-8859-1 as outlined in the meta tags.  THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: I disagree. Mixed language is very common. Many manuals and instructions documents are required to articulate in multiple languages. It's often inappropriate to translate quotes and excerpts. Even in conversation languages are often mixed. So if any document doesn't support mixed character sets then it's the document rendering framework that is broken, not the document design.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tika has an encoding detector. There are also commercial alternatives if you need, say, something in C++ and are in a position to spend money.

I can pretty much guarantee that each web page is in *one* encoding, but it's easy to be mistaken about *which one*.

Comment: I agree I decided to go with juniversalchardet.  It seems to be working well.  I may want to investigate a method of using meta tags as fall back if the juniversalchardet can't find a Charset.

Answer (score -2):

seems like issue with special characters. Check this [StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) if it helps. or any method there

edited: added this logic as he was not able to get code working

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String asd = "’";
        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(asd)); //output - &#8217;
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(asd)); //output - &rsquo;
}
```

Comment: @daniel It is strange people are thinking the only solution to a problem is what the the questionnaire has in mind. you could have waited for him to comment it is not a solution for him before u negate an answer.

Comment: No StringEscapeUtils will not work. I have tried.  In source the apostrophe is encoded as a apostrophe and not as a HTML &rsquo; so no this would not work.

Comment: @spitpsu Please check ur coding. I tried the logic and i got this output as shown above. Copy your character from the question and try the logic again or use my code. CODE WORKS FINE. Please accept the answer if it works for you. your question has already cost me 4 points

Comment: @Daniel hope u see that logic can be attained by my way also :P

Comment: Babu, I completely understand that yes the code that you have did execute correctly the first time, no problem with logic.  I simply was stating that the answer you gave was not the appropriate answer to the question.  I was asking a question in regards to analyzing character sets for HTML documents not how to transform specific characters, the URL I provided was simply an example.